# How to avoid WARN logs for conditional @StreamListener, if condition is not met?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream

With condition on StreamListener annotation, if this condition is not met DispatchingStreamListenerMessageHandler is logging WARN message with text:

```
Cannot find a @StreamListener matching for message with id: [some_id]
```

Example, imagine we have 3 microservices:

- AnimalService - producer application, that is going to produce **Dog** and **Cat** messages.
- DogService - consumer application, to consume only **Dog** messages.
- CatService - consumer application, to consume only **Cat** messages.

Animal application is sending a message and includes header parameter **type**:

```
public void handleEvent(Animal animal) {
    MessageBuilder<Animal> messageBuilder = MessageBuilder.withPayload(animal)
        .setHeader("type", animal.getType());
    bindings.itemEventOutput().send(messageBuilder.build());
}
```

Both DogService and CatService are going to consume this messages. Apparently DogService want to consume only "Dog" messages and CatService only "Cat" messages.

DogService will consume like this:

```
@StreamListener(target = "animal_events", condition = "headers['type']=='DOG'")
public void handleDogEvents(Message<String> message) {
    //important dog related logic
}
```

CatService will consume like this:

```
@StreamListener(target = "animal_events", condition = "headers['type']=='CAT'")
public void handleCatEvents(Message<String> message) {
    //important cat related logic
}
```

Because DogService is not handling Cat related messages and vice versa each service will have in a logs WARN message like this:

```
Cannot find a @StreamListener matching for message with id: [some_id]
```

I found two solution how to avoid this, but they are probably not the best one.

1. create in DogService another @StreamListener that will capture Cat events and do any logic there, just log a debug message
2. Change log level for org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding package to ERROR, but this could lead to missing some important WARN messages in logs.

I'm using spring-cloud-stream-3.0.3.

Is there any other better option (configuration property)? Or there is no other option rather  refactor my services ? Thanks.

Comment: Very clear question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotation programming model for s-c-stream is all but deprecated. For the past year we've been promoting functional programming model which provides for s more robust [routing mechanism](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_event_routing).

I also published a post with more details [here](https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/31/spring-cloud-stream-event-routing). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you use logback as your log framework, you can custom a log filter named ContentLogFilter extends Filter. You need override decide method. In this method, you just add one line of code, that is 'return event.getMessage().contains("Cannot find a @StreamListener matching for message") ? FilterRelay.DENY : FilterRelay.NEUTRAL;'. Then, it means the log filter will discard the log message if log message contains target log message. Otherwise, log filter will jump current filter and execute next filter.

```
public class ContentLogFilter extends Filter<ILoggingEvent> {

   @Override
   public FilterReply decide(ILoggingEvent event) {
      return event.getMessage().contains("Cannot find a @StreamListener 
             matching for message") ? FilterRelay.DENY : FilterRelay.NEUTRAL;
   }
}
```

Then, you need add your custom log filter in each appender of logback.xml config file.

```
<filter class="com.filter.ContentLogFilter" />
```

Attention please, your custom log filter should be placed on front of other filter.

I answer question for the first time in the platform. I just met the question and cost two days deal it. So I hope the answer can help more developer. That's all,Thanks!